# Requrejs: Optimize relative base path issue

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I am getting different value from require.toUrl() after optimizing with r.js

//---------------------here is my config file ----------------------------//

```
require.config({

    paths: {
        'view': '../partials'
    },

    deps: ['main']
});
```

//-----------------------main.js ----------------------------//

```
define(['require'], function (require) {
    'use strict';

     require.toUrl('./view/ngSlider.html')
});
```

when I run the code, I got the following path( without r.js optimize which is correct)

```
<script src="http://plvr.localhost/lib/require.js" data-main="http://plvr.localhost/js/config.js"></script>

(console)
http://plvr.localhost/js/../partials/ngSlider.html
```

When I run the code, I got following the path ( with r.js optimize which is incorrect)

```
<script src="http://plvr.localhost/js/dev.min.js"></script>
./../partials/ngSlider.html
```

In optimize verision of js file my base url is missing, and why I'm getting two different values. Please suggest me some solution or workaround.

Comment: Are you getting an error because of different urls?

Comment: yes it's not loading ngSlider.html file because of base path missing in optimize version